# Multiple ListView in an Activity, how to enter data?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, textview

I am developing an App where an Activity has 8 ListView, and I need to insert data in MySql each separately, how can I do this?

The ListView only shows data, no action when clicked, so it would be better to do it without the ListView, perhaps entering data into a TextView?

Comment: you'd have to assign an adapter to each and input data to the adapter like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should decide the best way to show your data. 8 listview in the same activity sounds a little strange to me. In a device like a tablet it would, maybe, be ok, but on a small device like a cell phone it will be VERY difficult to handle.

if you are going to show a LOT of data, listview is the best shot. but if is only one or two strings, use a textview.

anyway. to show the data in each listview you should create an adapter to each listview.

good luck!